# NoReverseMatch Django 2 Python

Tags: python, django

NoReverseMatch
Reverse for 'Edit_Product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/product/Edit_Product/(?P[0-9]+)$']

I could not understand the reason behind this error I tried looking for answers for around the web but nothing worked for me so far, I am new to django and trying to develop my skills if anyone can help please

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

forms.py

```
class EditProduct(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["category", "name", "image", "description",
                  "price", "available"]
```

views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def Edit_Product(request, id=None):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditProduct(request.POST, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'shop/product/Edit_Product.html', {'product': product, 'form':form})
    else:
        form = EditProduct(instance=product)
    return render(request,'shop/product/Edit_Product.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),

    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),

    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

    path('shop/Create_Product/', views.Create_Product, name='Create_Product'),

    path('shop/product/Edit_Product/<int:id>', views.Edit_Product, name='Edit_Product'),        

]
```

the templates look like this

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}


<title> Edit </title>


{% block content %}
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'shop:Edit_Product' id=Product.id  %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I would be really grateful for any help I have been having for days now and when modifying it I receive either this error or 404 error.

the error is showing me the detailproduct view in the browser I tried arranging them making edit before it and add it to the render line but alos no luck there 
This is how it looks like the view.py product detail just after the edit

```
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product,
                  'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```

the Image link is here for the Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qozlt.jpg)

Detail.html

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="product-detail">
    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
    <h2><a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.category }}</a></h2>
    <p class="price">${{ product.price }}</p>
    <form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
      {{ cart_product_form }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if request.user.is_staff %} 
          <a href="{% url "shop:Edit_Product" %}">Edit Product </a>
      {% endif %}
      <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
    </form>
    {{ product.description|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: This is most likely an error in a template, where you have `{% url 'Edit_Product' id=product.id %}` or something like that. The error says that the `id` is empty. Where does this error occur (when fetching which url?). Look at the entire error trace!

Comment: tried that but still not working at all

Comment: As I said the error seems to be in your template not in your view. Show us detail.html. Is that the template you’re showing above?

Comment: Why didn’t you read my first comment? I said “look for `{% url %}` tag with `Edit_Product` in it”. Well you have one in your template and it sets `id=Product.id`. Now think: why is this `id` empty? Hmmmm maybe `Product` isn’t defined? Indeed. In your context you define `product` not `Product`.

Comment: That was for the other template. For the detail template you just added also look at the {% url %}. It doesn’t pass the id at all! But your Edit_Product url pattern requires an id.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dirkgroten it worked just fine now, I am so gratefull for your help Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to understand the error:

> NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'Edit_Product' with no arguments not found.

This error is saying that you asked Django to **reverse** a url pattern with the **name** `Edit_Product`, that it expects an argument but no argument was given.

Indeed, this is your path:

```
path('shop/product/Edit_Product/<int:id>', views.Edit_Product, name='Edit_Product')
```

so in order to reverse it, you need to pass it the argument `id`:

```
# in a view
from django.urls import reverse
reverse('Edit_Product', kwargs={'id': <some_id>})

# in a template
{% url 'Edit_Product' id=<some_id> %}
```

You can now just search in your entire project for `reverse('Edit_Product'` and `{% url 'Edit_Product'` or narrow it down like this:

- First, this is **not** an error in your *Edit_Product* view (at least not necessarily), it can happen in any view that reverses the url pattern. You need to look at the rest of the error message which tells you which url was requested or which view was used.
- You already saw that this was happening in the `product_detail()` view, in the `render()` method actually.
- So the error was triggered when rendering the template, in this case the *detail.html* template. Here you should check for `{% url 'Edit_Product' ... %}`.
- There you have it, `{% url 'Edit_Product' %}` with no argument. Fix it by adding the `product.id`.